# Can't get my detail view to show

Tags: iphone

I have a tabbed bar main window with four tabs, one of which is a list. This list is empty at first but when I click a "+" I am presented with a modal view of available options like this

```
- (IBAction)addThing:(id)sender {
    MJAvailableThingsViewController *controller = [self availableThingsViewController];
    [self presentModalViewController:availableThingsViewController animated:YES];
    [controller setEditing:YES animated:NO];
}
```

This works.

The list of things has a UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton on each row. This was done with the accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath. This works as well.

When I click the little blue button in this view the delegate accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath is called. This works.

However, in accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath I want to present a detail view of the thing and this is where I encounter problems:

The delegate looks like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSLog(@"accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath");
    NSLog(@"Tapped row %d", [indexPath row]);

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:thingDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

The program enters this code but nothing happens, that is I get the NSLog output but no new window. I am very new at this so please forgive me if this is obvious; to me it is, however, not... :-)

Comment: How are you initializing thingDetailViewController

Comment: I tried overriding the getter thus:
- (ThingDetailViewController *)thingDetailViewController {
    // Instantiate the add view controller if necessary.
    if (thingDetailViewController == nil) {
        thingDetailViewController = [ThingDetailViewController alloc];
    }
    return thingDetailViewController;
}

Comment: try: thingDetailViewController = [[ThingDetailViewController alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `navigationController`?  It sounds like you have a `TabController` but not a `NavigationController`.

Check `[self navigationController]`, is it set to anything?

Here's a similar question:
[Tab Bar Application With Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller)

Comment: No, I don't have a navigationcontroller. The question you pointed me to is indeed very similar to my problem but I have not been able to use the advice therein, mainly due to inability. Bother.

My latest attempt rendered me a view with just a table for availableThings, instead of the table with a title bar on top and the add button I used to have.