# How do I add a tab bar controller to a navigation-controller-based application?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am beginning iPhone application developer, and so I'm not sure how to start the creation of a navigation-controller-based application which uses a tab bar controller in part of it.  Do you have suggestions for where to start with this?

Comment: Have you tried googling for tutorials?

Comment: @Jeff, brace yourself for the flaming!

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, this may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller

Answer (score 1):

These links are a good place to start:

- [Howto articles for iPhone
  development, Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/howto-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)
- [Where
  can I find beginner iPhone
  tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142014/where-can-i-find-beginner-iphone-tutorials)
- [Best Book or Article
  to learn iphone development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758748/best-book-or-article-to-learn-iphone-development)
- [Getting started with Objective-C and
  the iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066275/getting-started-with-objective-c-and-the-iphone-sdk)

There's a lot [out there](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+beginner+getting+started+books+iphone&btnG=Google), it's a little overwhelming at first.  One way to get started is to pick a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758748/best-book-or-article-to-learn-iphone-development/758775#758775) and go through all the examples.

Answer (score 1):

The Book "Beginning iPhone Development" is pretty good for GUI-Stuff. You could buy it.

But here's a online tutorial:
http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You don't!

But you can add a `UINavigationController` to a `UITabBar`.