# tabbar and navigation controller in view based application

Tags: iphone

I am making a view based application in which there is need of tabbar as well as navigation bar controller according to requirement. I have put tabbar controller it is working fine but unable to put navigation controller. Anyone know how to add tabbar and navigation bar in view based application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab Bar Application With Navigation Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [S.O. topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller), it's what you are looking for.