# Add a navigation control to a single tab in xcode 4

Tags: iphone

I am fairly new to programming with objective-c and xcode 4 and I am trying to make a tab bar application and add a navigation control to a specific tab.

I am able to add a navigation controller inside the tab bar controller, by clicking dragging the navigation controller into the tab bar controller of the MainWindow.xib window. However, by doing this and linking the class and nib to the corresponding view controller and view, respectively, this adds a new tab, which I don't want (as I want a specific/already in existence tab to also contain the nav controller).
Thanks.

Comment: It's possible, check out this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to do, but as my understanding, you want navigation controller under tabbar item that is already existed in the tabbar controller. It's not good practice to do it in that way. Rather than that, try add navigation controller first and then add ViewController inside of it (which makes your life easier). Usually Navigation Controller is root of ViewController, but not vice verse. Hope this help.