# Auto-Resizing a dynamic view when rotated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I have a tab bar application where everything is working fine.  I have rotations of the device all working fine with the various Tab Bar View controllers.

Alas it was suggested that a couple of the View Controllers needed a help page.  To this end I created a new ViewController that contains a UIWebView (where help can be built into an HTML file).

I create the new "HelpViewController" as follows:

```
mpHelpPage     = [[HelpPageViewController alloc] init];
[mTabBarController.view addSubview: mpHelpPage.view];
[mpHelpPage retain];

mpHelpPage.view.alpha = 0.75f;
```

This brings up the help page no problems when I'm in portait mode.  Unfortunately when I'm in landscape mode and I do the above code it adds the HelpViewController in Portrait (meaning it extends off the bottom of the screen).

As such when I alloc the ViewController above I need some way of telling the ViewController to rotate to the current device orientation.

I am, however, at a loss as to how to get it to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I handle this annoyance by putting an orientation check in `viewWillAppear:`, e.g.

```
if (self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
    self.interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    // custom code or call willRotate
} else {
    // custom code or call willRotate
}
```

You can also do this if you prefer

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
    // custom code or call willRotate
} else {
    // custom code or call willRotate
}
```

Comment: How would you go about doing an orientation check and do I have to manually move everything around?  Can I just re-size the view controller's super view and expect all the sub views to resize as well?

Comment: You can resize the superview so long as every subview has an autoresizing mask. I prefer to call my `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` function to avoid redundant code.

Comment: Understood.  But how do i know the devices orientation?

Comment: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`

Comment: Should I just be able to call "[self willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] duration:1.0f];"? because that doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: @Goz: Apparently not. I put my animated rotation code into a separate method that I call from `willRotate...` and I also call that method from `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: So, in summary, there isn't a simple "rotateTheDamnedThingNow" call? ;)

Comment: Ok I've used something similar I check the device orientation and set the frame by swapping the width/height around on the view's frame before calling setNeedsLayout.

Answer (score 2):

you should either set the `frame`-property of your subview in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` of your ViewController

or you write your own View and set the frame-property in `layoutSubviews` of your View

The added Subview should handle the layout of its subviews.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've added `HelpViewController` as a subview and no `UIViewController` controls it, it will not be resized. You can resize `HelpViewController`'s view manually by detecting a change in the orientation in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method of  the current `UIViewController`. This method passes the current orientation as its argument, so just check which is the current orientation and set a frame accordingly as:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if((interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
        mpHelpPage.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,300);
    else
        mpHelpPage.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
    return YES;
}
```

Or, Instead of adding `HelpViewController`as a subView, try `[self.navigationController pushViewController:HelpViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: Then you should push it onto the stack of view controllers. Right now, you've still only added it as a subview !

Comment: But I'm not using a navigation controller ... I'm using a tab bar controller ... If i use PushViewController onto the tab bar controller's navigation controller than, unsurprisingly, nothing happens.

Comment: Agreed, this would work only if you already had a navigation controller for a [particular tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller)...that's why you have to manually resize it in your case.