# Add Navigation Bar in Tabbar Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab Bar Application With Navigation Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369128/tab-bar-application-with-navigation-controller)

My Xcode version is 4.3.2. i Want to add navigation bar in tabbar based application.

Thanks

Comment: UINavigationBar *bar;
 bar.topItem.title = @"First";

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationItem.title = @"First";
but both are not working.

Comment: my bank number is XXXCCCYYYZZZ, I want a million dollars added to it.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry about the comment to Rocks, but that was really what went through my mind when I saw this question :D

Answer (score 4):

For example, you can make it by using storyboard.

[image: ss]

Answer (score 4):

In your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method you can see something like

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
.
.
.   

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController, secondViewController, nil];
```

Add the object of `FirstViewController` to `UINavigationController` object as below

```
UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
.
.
.
//And in the tabbarController array add the navigationController Object instaed if FirstViewControllerObject
 self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstNavController, secondViewController, nil];
```

And its done. Now your `FirstViewController` will be treated as navigationController and it will have navigationbar.

**Edit**

If you Just want the navigation bar then you can either insert it from `xib` or add the `UINavigationBar` as a subview in `self.view`